# Proof for positive integer

Tags: induction

Prove that for any positive integers $m$ and $n$,  there exists a set of $n$ consecutive positive integers each of which is divisible by a number of the form $d^m$ where $d$ is some integer in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I imagine $d=1$is not intended. Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $p_1,p_2,..,p_n$ be pairwise distinct primes. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the system
$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{p_1^m} \\
x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p_2^m} \\
.... \\
x+n-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p_n^m}$$
has solutions.

Comment: May I expand on how one can use the Chinese remainder theorem? You say hint is all

Comment: Note: If $x$ satisfies all the equations simultaneously, then $p_1^m|x$, $p_2^m|(x+1),\ldots p_n^m|(x+n-1)$, so you have your desired consecutive integers.

Comment: Could any one please elaborate I am just a beginner